# Ajax Star Rating not working

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax

Here's what I currently have:

```
.starRating{
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.FilledStars{
    background-image: url("filter star.png");
}

.WaitingStars {
    background-image: url("filter star empty.png");
}

.EmptyStars {
    background-image: url("filter star empty.png");
}

<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
    <asp:Button ID="btnPersonal1" class="btn btn-primary" runat="server" Text="Personal" ForeColor="White" />
    <asp:Button ID="btnAcademic1" class="btn btn-outline-primary" runat="server" Text="Academic" OnClick="btnAcademic1_Click" />
    <asp:Button ID="btnAthletic1" class="btn btn-outline-primary" runat="server" Text="Athletic" OnClick="btnAthletic1_Click" />
    <asp:Button ID="btnNotes1" class="btn btn-outline-primary" runat="server" Text="Notes" OnClick="btnNotes1_Click" />
    <asp:Button ID="btnSchedule1" class="btn btn-outline-primary" runat="server" Text="Schedule" OnClick="btnSchedule1_Click"/>
    <br />
    <br />

     <div>
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>

        <cc1:Rating ID="Rating1" runat="server"
            StarCssClass="starRating"
            FilledStarCssClass="FilledStars"
            WaitingStarCssClass="WaitingStars"
            EmptyStarCssClass="EmptyStars"
            MaxRating="5" 
            CurrentRating="1">

        </cc1:Rating>

    </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
       </div>
</panel>
```

I'm not sure why it's not working.  I've check the image url's multiple times and everything matches.  I just need the user to add their own star ratings to the page, but the stars aren't even appearing to rate.

Comment: If you open this page in Chrome, and then hit F12 to open developer tools, switch to the network tab, and then reload the page, do you see any resources that are failing to load?

Comment: what folder do you have the star images in?

Comment: @Markus content.css is not loading

Comment: @wazz they're not in a folder.  I had them in an images folder originally, but when the images weren't loading I took them out, hoping it was the url causing the issue.

Comment: @Price Does content.css contain your css included in your example?